# angular2 uncaught error when following ng-book-2 simple reddit clone example

Tags: angular, typescript

I recently started to work through the ng-book 2 book and i'm having some issues running the first example project...  i've successfully ran the completed example from the book's code but can't get my attempt at that example to work.  When I run ng serve the app gets compiled with no errors and I can see it at localhost:4200 but only the header of index.html shows.  The part where the angular content is supposed to load just says loading...  I get the following error in my  chrome console...  Any idea what might be going wrong?

ng-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a misplaced div tag...  This was a very vague error message.  I would have never thought it could be a HTML issue...